# Android: Database delete not working. Function call skipped in debugger

Tags: java, android, debugging

I've written a database manager to handle the queries in my Android application and the function that I use to delete a row does some weird stuff. Here's the function:

```
public synchronized boolean removeChannel(String channel_name) {
        IMrekMessageDbAdapter messageAdapter = new IMrekMessageDbAdapter(this.context);
        messageAdapter.open();
        long id = getChannelId(channel_name);
        if (!messageAdapter.clearChannel(id)) {
            // return false if we can't clear the messages for the channel
            // this likely means that the channel doesn't actually exist and something
            // is messed up.
            return false;
        }
        boolean ret = database.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{((Long)id).toString()}) > 0;
        return ret;
    }
```

Now, with the code like this, it hits the if which evaluates to false and therefore skips it. However it skips the assignment of `ret` and goes right to the return statement (and therefore also skips the `database.delete()` call. The debugger also doesn't show `ret` in the scope.

Another question pointed out that sometimes it might skip lines because of the way the Android compiler optimizes the bytecode, since that is what it's really tracing through and not the java. However, if I comment out the `return false;` inside the if it doesn't skip the `database.delete()` call/assignment to `ret`. And it actually does delete the line it is supposed to.

My question is basically: Why would it skip the rest of the function because of a `return` statement inside an if block that is not getting executed?

Comment: I suggest that you do `Clean` (`Project` -> `Clean`) the project first, then redebug. I suspect that debuger got "confused" and shows wrong lines. It seems that `if` condition is evaluated to true and `return false` is executed.

Comment: I don't know about that, I refreshed and cleaned the project several times and also restarted eclipse, my computer, etc. As I've seen in documentation, raw types, like boolean, are always initialized to a 0 value, So even if the function call was skipped, `ret` would be initialized to false which is what it was returning. If I stepped into the function that it calls in the if condition, I could see that it was returning a true value and therefore, as it was doing, it should skip over the block.

Comment: Other possible solution is to change the `if` to `if-else` and put the last 2 lines in the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it was because of the return statement inside of the `if`. I learned that you are always only supposed to have one return statement inside a function. As demonstrated here, having others can cause problems. Despite not going into the `if` block, it was executing the first return.